# JavaScript: toggle links active/deactive

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, toggle

**How do I toggle HTML links from being active / deactive using JavaScript?**

Within my HTML, I have 2 hyper links that call a JavaScript function to sort a table:

```
<a href="javascript:sort('asc');">ASC</a> | <a href="javascript:sort('desc');">DESC</a>
```

What I would like to do is when someone clicks the "ASC" link, it then deactives the "ASC" hyperlink (no longer a link) so that only now the "DESC" link is active.

Then, if the person presses the "DESC" link, it then disables the "DESC" link and re-enables the "ASC" link.

Essentially, I want to toggle between which link is active, either: "ASC" or "DESC"

I assume you can do this with JavaScript but am not sure how?

Any ideas?

Comment: What HTML0equivalent to you want for a link being "disabled"? I can think of various possibilities (each easy to achieve in JS, at least if you add usable `id=` attributes to your `<a>` tags:-) but I'm not sure which one you have in mind!

Comment: "Disabled" as in, no longer a hyperlink (remove the <a> tag)

Comment: But when I say "remove the <a> tag", don't remove the "ASC" or "DESC" text. Make sense?

Comment: toggle the ASC and DESC from being links to not being links (but still displayed as text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't strictly "remove" the A tag, but removes the "linkness" (by removing the href) from the tag.

Edit: slightly better version (now tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

  function mySort( sortorder) {

      // enable the other link
      otherOrder = (sortorder == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
      document.getElementById(otherOrder).setAttribute("href", "#");
      document.getElementById(otherOrder).onclick = function() {mySort(this.id)};

      //disable this link
      document.getElementById(sortorder).removeAttribute("href");
      document.getElementById(sortorder).onclick = "";

      //perform the sort
      doSort(sortorder);
  }
</script>

<a id="asc" href="#" onclick="mySort(this.id)" >ASC</a> | <a id="desc" href="#" onclick="mySort(this.id)" >DESC</a>
```

Comment: @Stobor, this appears to work BUT, the disabled link is still blue. So it still appears to be a link even though when you mouse over/hover over the disabled link - it's not a link.  How can I make the disabled link look just like text?

Comment: @TomHankers: Do you have any css applied to A tags? If so, they should be applied to A:link rather than just A. (On my test page without any css, the blue and the underline both disappear when clicked.)

Answer (score 0):

you could use:
in your script section:

```
var asc = true;
```

and your html

```
<a href="javascript:if (asc) { sort('asc'); asc=!asc; }; ">ASC</a> | <a href="javascript:if (!asc) { sort('desc'); asc=!asc; }; ">DESC</a>
```

(though it might be better to spin those off into functions)

**EDIT**

as per author's comment, 
if you want to completely "remove" the links, switch display:none and display:inline on the elements.
e.g.

```
<a id="asc" href="if (asc) { sort('asc'); asc=!asc; this.style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById("desc").style.display = 'inline';}; ">ASC</a> | <a id="desc" href="if (!asc) { sort('desc'); asc=!asc; this.style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById("asc").style.display = 'inline';}; ">DESC</a>
```

If you want to replace them with spans, then use the same technique to show/hide their span counterparts

Comment: I don't understand, how would this toggle the text "ASC" and "DESC" from being links to not being links?

Comment: it wouldn't stop them from being "links". it would stop the sort function from running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with jQuery? If so, you might consider the various table-sorting plugins out there, such as [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). I don't have any use for it at the moment, but a number of shops in my organization have incorporated it. For bonus points, the documentation at that link seems pretty comprehensive.

jQuery can also give you solid control over whether the `<a>` is present. Hopefully someone with more experience can stop by w/ some code examples demonstrating that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make them links, use another element, for example a `span`.

```
<span onclick="sort('asc');">ASC</span> | <span onclick="sort('desc');">DESC</span>
```

Then use JavaScript to set a class that defines a visual style on the active item, you can toggle this on each `span`.

Your sort function can also determine whether or not the supplied direction is valid and simply do nothing.